# ListPreference Default not being set in Preferences

Tags: java, android

Edit: it's actually only my ListPreference defaults not being set.

When my application starts, there are no ListPreference defaults set despite my call to setDefaultValues. Is it because I'm setting the defaults in the wrong context?

My preferences all have keys and a default value so I'm not sure what is wrong.

My MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
    updateButtons();
  }

  /*
  Function to open the preferences screen.
   */
  public void openSettings(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, PreferencesActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
  }


}
```

My PreferencesActivity.java

```
public class PreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
  }

  public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
  }
}
```

My preferences.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<PreferenceScreen
    android:title="@string/btn_pref1"
    android:persistent="false">
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="btn1_name"
        android:title="@string/btn_name"
        android:defaultValue="@string/btn_name" />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="btn1_cmd"
        android:title="@string/btn_cmd_name"
        android:defaultValue="@string/btn_default_cmd" />
    <ListPreference
        android:key="btn1_color"
        android:title="@string/btn_color"
        android:entries="@array/colorArray"
        android:entryValues="@array/colorValues"
        android:defaultValue="#024c9b"/>
</PreferenceScreen>

<PreferenceScreen
    android:title="@string/btn_pref2"
    android:persistent="false">
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="btn2_name"
        android:title="@string/btn_name"
        android:defaultValue="@string/btn_name" />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="btn2_cmd"
        android:title="@string/btn_cmd_name"
        android:defaultValue="@string/btn_default_cmd" />
    <ListPreference
        android:key="btn2_color"
        android:title="@string/btn_color"
        android:entries="@array/colorArray"
        android:entryValues="@array/colorValues"
        android:defaultValue="#024c9b"/>
</PreferenceScreen>

<PreferenceScreen
    android:title="@string/btn_pref3"
    android:persistent="false">
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="btn3_name"
        android:title="@string/btn_name"
        android:defaultValue="@string/btn_name" />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="btn3_cmd"
        android:title="@string/btn_cmd_name"
        android:defaultValue="@string/btn_default_cmd" />
    <ListPreference
        android:key="btn3_color"
        android:title="@string/btn_color"
        android:entries="@array/colorArray"
        android:entryValues="@array/colorValues"
        android:defaultValue="#024c9b"/>
</PreferenceScreen>

<PreferenceScreen
    android:title="@string/btn_pref4"
    android:persistent="false">
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="btn4_name"
        android:title="@string/btn_name"
        android:defaultValue="@string/btn_name" />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="btn4_cmd"
        android:title="@string/btn_cmd_name"
        android:defaultValue="@string/btn_default_cmd" />
    <ListPreference
        android:key="btn4_color"
        android:title="@string/btn_color"
        android:entries="@array/colorArray"
        android:entryValues="@array/colorValues"
        android:defaultValue="#024c9b"/>
</PreferenceScreen>

<PreferenceScreen
    android:title="@string/btn_pref5"
    android:persistent="false">
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="btn5_name"
        android:title="@string/btn_name"
        android:defaultValue="@string/btn_name" />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="btn5_cmd"
        android:title="@string/btn_cmd_name"
        android:defaultValue="@string/btn_default_cmd" />
    <ListPreference
        android:key="btn5_color"
        android:title="@string/btn_color"
        android:entries="@array/colorArray"
        android:entryValues="@array/colorValues"
        android:defaultValue="#024c9b"/>
</PreferenceScreen>

<PreferenceScreen
    android:title="@string/btn_pref6"
    android:persistent="false">
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="btn6_name"
        android:title="@string/btn_name"
        android:defaultValue="@string/btn_name" />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="btn6_cmd"
        android:title="@string/btn_cmd_name"
        android:defaultValue="@string/btn_default_cmd" />
    <ListPreference
        android:key="btn6_color"
        android:title="@string/btn_color"
        android:entries="@array/colorArray"
        android:entryValues="@array/colorValues"
        android:defaultValue="#024c9b"/>
</PreferenceScreen>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: post your `R.xml.preferences`..code

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling:

```
 PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getBaseContext(), R.xml.preferences, false);
```

in your `PreferencesActivity` onCreate()

code:

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getBaseContext(), R.xml.preferences, false);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
  }
```

if that's not work: clear application data. `Uninstall` and `reinstall` the app

Comment: Thanks, though I found that some of my preferences are saving, namely the EditText ones, but somehow the ListPreferences are not being set as the default value. I get a "" when I call getString on one.

Answer (score 0):

Clear application data, then uninstall and reinstall the app.
Strange solution, I know but it worked in my case.